# Self hosted open source BrowserStack alternative?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, software-testing, web-services

I find myself needing to test websites design, but BrowserStack and similar and comparable alternatives are all a bit to hefty in terms of their price ranges.

Are there any self hosted options that provide similar robustness for testing on many mobile and desktop platforms like this?